# Game Over system is not functioning correctly

Tags: html

I'm very new to coding with HTML and I am trying to recreate a simple version of Whack a Mole for my high school English class. The game seems to be running fine until it reaches the "Game Over" part, where issues start to occur, I'm not really too sure whats happening and causing the bugs. Also 2 of the objects (collar and Tail) don't scale to the rest of the objects. Thank you for reading.

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="puppic.ico">
   <title>Pet a Pup!</title>
  <style>

   body{ background-image:url(mountain.png); width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
     
   
   .dog{
    background-color:rgb(185, 122, 87);
    border-radius:80px 80px 75px 75px;
    height:46.5%;
    width:10%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background-image:url(dog2.png);
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0% 5%;
   }
  
   .left_ear{
    background-color:rgb(142, 88, 60);
    border-radius:80px 80px 65px 65px;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    min-width: 32%;
    padding-top: 50%;
    right:-13%;
   }
  
   .right_ear{
    background-color:rgb(142, 88, 60);
    border-radius:80px 80px 65px 65px;
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    min-width: 32%;
    padding-top: 50%;
    left:-13%;
   }

   .bottom_left_paw{
    background-color:rgb(182, 114, 78);
    border-radius:80px 80px 100px 100px;
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    min-width: 25%;
    padding-top: 60%;
    left:0%;
    bottom:-10%;
   }

   .bottom_right_paw{
    background-color:rgb(182, 114, 78);
    border-radius:80px 80px 100px 100px;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    min-width: 25%;
    padding-top: 60%;
    right:0%;
    bottom:-10%;
   }
   .top_left_paw{
    background-color:rgb(182, 114, 78);
    border-radius:100px 100px 80px 80px;
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    min-width: 25%;
    padding-top: 60%;
    left:-20%;
    transform: rotate(-40deg);
    bottom:35%;
   }

   .top_right_paw{
    background-color:rgb(182, 114, 78);
    border-radius:100px 100px 80px 80px;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    min-width: 25%;
    padding-top: 60%;
    right:-20%;
    transform: rotate(40deg);
    bottom:35%;
   }

   .stomach{
    background-color:rgb(230, 207, 166);
    border-radius:100px 100px 100px 100px;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    min-width: 50%;
    height: 12%;
    padding-top: 50%;
    left: 25.5%;
    bottom:11%;
    border-radius: 70%;
   }

   .collar{
    border-radius:100px 100px 100px 100px;
    position:absolute;
    padding-top: 0%;
    float:left;
    min-width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
      box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 0 rgb(207, 16, 26);
     border-radius: 30px 30px 140px 30px;
    left: 10%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    bottom:49%;
   }

   .tail{
    position:absolute;
       width: 0;
      height: 0;
       border-top: 60px solid #875438;
       border-left: 10px solid transparent;
       border-right: 150px solid transparent;
    left: 47%;
    bottom:6%;
    z-index:-1;
   }

  #dog1 { left: 10%; }
  #dog2 { left: 45%; }
  #dog3 { left: 80%; }
   
       .try_again {
           cursor: pointer;
      }

   .score{font-family:impact; font-size:3.5vw; position:absolute; right:5%; z-index:3;}
   
  </style>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    
    var add = 0;
         var gameStarted = false;

    function game_over(){
     gameStarted = false;
     jQuery('.dog').animate({'top':'100%'},500);
     jQuery('.score').html('GAME OVER');
     jQuery('.score').append('<div class="try_again">TRY AGAIN</div>');
    }
    function start(){
            gameStarted = true;
     add = 0;
     jQuery('.score').html('Score: ' + add);
     jQuery('.dog').animate({'top':'0%'},3500,function(){
      game_over();
      jQuery('.try_again').click(function(){start();});
     }); 
    }   

    jQuery('.dog').click(function(){
     if (!gameStarted) return;
     jQuery(this).css('background-image','url(dog1.png)');
     jQuery(this).stop().animate({'top':'100%'},1700, function(){ 
      add = add - (-1);     
      jQuery('.score').html('Score: ' + add);
      jQuery(this).css('background-image','url(dog2.png)');
                 jQuery(this).animate({'top':'0%'},2500,function(){
                         game_over();
                         jQuery('.try_again').click(function(){start();});
                     }); 
     });
    });
    start();
   });

  </script>

 </head>

 <body>

  <div class="score">Score: 0</div>

  <div class="dog" id="dog1">
   <div class="left_ear"></div>
   <div class="right_ear"></div>
   <div class="top_left_paw"></div>
   <div class="top_right_paw"></div>
   <div class="bottom_left_paw"></div>
   <div class="bottom_right_paw"></div>
   <div class="stomach"></div>
   <div class="collar"></div>
   <div class="tail"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dog" id="dog2">
   <div class="left_ear"></div>
   <div class="right_ear"></div>
   <div class="top_left_paw"></div>
   <div class="top_right_paw"></div>
   <div class="bottom_left_paw"></div>
   <div class="bottom_right_paw"></div>
   <div class="stomach"></div>
   <div class="collar"></div>
   <div class="tail"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dog" id="dog3">
   <div class="left_ear"></div>
   <div class="right_ear"></div>
   <div class="top_left_paw"></div>
   <div class="top_right_paw"></div>
   <div class="bottom_left_paw"></div>
   <div class="bottom_right_paw"></div>
   <div class="stomach"></div>
   <div class="collar"></div>
   <div class="tail"></div>
  </div>
  

 </body>

  <audio controls autoplay loop volume="0.1">
   <source src="Doggo1.mp3">
  
    </audio>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a side note : instead of the word JQuery, I suggest you to just use $  sign. You'd spare some time and write less

Comment: okay, Ill try that, thanks!